# Jquery ajax is not being called inside jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a aspx form with a method inside . When i click a checkbox an event fires in jquery for that checkbox and inside i want to call ajax funcion that calls the method from the codebehind.

The jquery event triggers the problem is the ajax inside is not being called i think.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#chkReservaSemanal').change(function () {
    if ($("#chkReservaSemanal").is(":checked")) {
    alert("checkEvent"); 
        $.ajax({

          alert("checkAjax");

            type: "POST",
            url: "AltaDeReserva.aspx/test",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });

    }

});
```

});

Here is the codebehind method.

```
  [WebMethod]
    public void test()
    {
        u = (Usuario)Session["Usuario"];
        int idUsuario = u.IdUsuario;
        //c = (Cancha)Session["CanchaReserva"];
        //int idCancha = c.IdCancha;


        String precio = calcularPrecioReserva(idUsuario, Convert.ToInt32(ddlCanchas.SelectedValue)).ToString();
        if (precio == "0")
        {
            llbPrecioValor.Text = "La reserva no tiene costo.";
        }
        else
        {
            llbPrecioValor.Text = precio;
        }
    }
```

*The codebehind method works when called in codebehind.
* alert("checkAjax");  does not fire.
* alert("checkEvent"); does fire.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's expecting a JSON return value, your function is void.

Comment: take out the alert within `$.ajax({`

Comment: how can i set it to expect void

Answer (score 0):

If you check your console (Hit F12 then select Console in FF and Chrome) you should see this causes a syntax error

```
    $.ajax({

      alert("checkAjax");

        type: "POST",
```

[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) expects a [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject). You've added `alert("checkAjax");` inside it, invalidating the syntax. Remove it.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AltaDeReserva.aspx/test",
```